# Why does Safari give a different initial value for window.scrollY on a scrolled page?

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, webkit

So, take a webpage that has a height larger than that of the viewport.

You scroll down `x` pixels from the top.

You log `window.scrollY` to the console and it prints the int `x`.

`x` is some number larger than 0 (and less than a maximum that's irrelevant).

Now, you refresh the page. The browser renders where you scrolled to before. The following script runs:

```
// script.js

window.onload = function() {
  console.log(window.scrollY);
}
```

The expected output is `x`.

Testing in Firefox printed `x`.

Testing in Safari printed `0`.

Additionally:

Safari prints `x` accurately once scrolling begins.

If the `window` object is printed on load, the `scrollY` property reads `x`, not `0`.

Why is there this discrepancy?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't control the action in Safari, in all browsers, if you changed the history page, the scroll will be at x=0, y=0, in Chrome or Firefox they save the x and y position and scroll you to that point but in Safari this won't happen, also, sometimes it will be triggered after the first scroll, some time never happened.

Comment: But, Safari does visually scroll me to the saved x and y position. It functions correctly. But when I try to read the `window.scrollY` value on window load, it gives me the incorrect value. Printing the `window` object yields the correct value, but that's not what my program would be using.

Comment: The pageYOffset property is an alias for the scrollY property, check pageYOffset, it may solve the problem.

Comment: pageYOffset prints the same value.